# Finite covers of the unit ball in an infinite dimensional Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Consider an infinite dimensional Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$ with orthonormal basis vectors $(e_1,e_2,...)$.

Denoting a ball centered at point $p$ with radius $r$ as $B(p,r)$, of course for $r\geq 1$, $B(0,r)$ trivially covers the unit ball.

I was wondering if the following statement is true:

> There does not exist a finite covering of the unit ball $B(0,1)$ consisting of
>   balls with radius less than 1.

I think this is because for $r<1$, $B(p,r)$ can only contain a finite number of the orthonormal basis vectors. In other words, there are always an infinite number of $e_k$ that are contained in the unit ball but not in $\bigcup_{k=1}^n B(p_k,r)$, for any choice of centers $\{p_1,p_2,...,p_n\}$.

Is this correct? It seems pretty remarkable to me that a single ball of radius 1 can cover the unit ball (trivially), but to cover it with balls of radius 0.9999, an infinite number are needed.

Comment: It should not be “remarkable” to you at all: look at the unit ball in the *finite*-dimensional space $\Bbb R^{40000}$, call its volume $V$. Now consider the ball of radius $0.9999$ in the same $40000$-dimensional space. Its volume is less than $.0184V$. You’ll need at least $55$ balls of this size to cover the unit ball. (And that is a very crude calculation.)

Comment: And in fact this can be turned into a proof: you can project $H$ down to a finite-dimensional Hilbert space of any finite dimension.